# How to force ollydbg to copy a self modified executable?

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, ollydbg

I am working on an executable with self modifying code. Unfortunately, Ollydbg does not detect that the executable has "changed' despite it rather obviously XORing itself.

Normally, I would choose "copy to executable" -> "All modifications", press copy all, when a new window has opened, just press right mouse button and press "save file"

However, Olly detects no "modifications" no matter how many times I try to force it to analyze the file.

How can I force it to do what I want?

Comment: Why not use something more modern, like windbg or ida?

Comment: Because I was completing a contest where I was forced to use ollydbg.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set a hardware breakpoint on write on the section that the 'Xor' ing happens